# Slashes in property in Url string Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, encoding, slash

I'm developing a Java Spring MVC app for my job. We always had a problem when we have slashes in URLs. We are using Java 8 and Tomcat 7.
In the JSP of "current-page" we have this href:

```
 <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><a id="column" style="color: #EB9316" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/other-page/${c.property}/${dto.year}">${c.property}</a></td>
```

Here we pass the property of the object and the year as parameters. In "other-page" we take property and year and filter the object c on the DB.
The issue is that property is a string that can sometimes have slashes in the name like "thing/otherthing" and we have to use both year and property to filter in the other page. The year is taken from the context of the page, it does not give problems.

Following the code from "other-page" Java controller:

```
@GetMapping("/user/other-page/{property}/{year}")
public String homeUserOtherPageFilter(@PathVariable String property, @PathVariable Integer year, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    property= URLDecoder.decode(property, "UTF-8");
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("property", property);
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("year", year);
    return "redirect:/user/other-page";
}
```

With the slashes in the name i get error 404. I tried to encode the slash using this code in "current-page" java Controller.

```
  try {
        for (chapter chapter: chapters) {
            chapter.setProperty(URLEncoder.encode(chapter.getProperty(), "UTF-8")); 
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        logger.debug("Url encode failed ", e);
    }
```

But still this does not work, even with the URL encoded Tomcat gives me error 404 and doesn't even reach other-page controller to decode. The precise error is this if I click on the "thing/otherthing" link if I'm on the 2020 page in "current-page":

> The requested resource [/application/user/other-page/2020/thing%2Fotherthing] is not available

Of course with the property without the slashes everything works well. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I resolved the issue. For some strange reason Tomcat does not like the conversion of "/" into "%2F" but, for some reason unknown to me, accepts the encode of "/" as "%252F" which is given by encoding the parameter twice. So I just had to change the code in the current-page Java controller into

```
try {
    for (chapter chapter: chapters) {
        chapter.setProperty(URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.encode(chapter.getProperty(), "UTF-8"), "UTF-8")); 
    }
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
    logger.debug("Url encode failed ", e);
}
```

Now everything works fine.